# jQuery serialize() always empty

Tags: javascript, html

I can't get this script working. Every time I send a file the script need to do one ajax request and send to server the file, but, serialize always send empty string.

My Javascript

```
$('#upload-button input:file').change(function() {
    $('#upload-text').text('Sending file...');

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "?url=images/send",
        data: $('#image-upload').serialize(),

        success: function(response) {
            if(response.error) {
                $('#upload-text').text(response.error);
            } else if(response.success) {
                $('#upload-text').text('Image send');
            }
        },
    });
})
```

My HTML

```
<form name="image-upload" id="image-upload" action="?url=imagens/enviar" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="selected-image" id="upload-hidden" value="" />
</form>
```

When I have selected a file, result from `alert($('#image-upload').serialize());`:

```
// EMPTY //
```

Result from `alert($('#image-upload input:file').attr('value'))`:

```
ponte-vecchio.jpg
```

Comment: I think you cannot send multipart data like files via ajax with jQuery... some modern browsers can do that with HTML5... rather I suggest you use the technique to submit a file into an iframe and observe the load event of that iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). It supports HTML5 file uploads and can fallback to a hidden iframe if the browser is too old.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to submit the file then you will have to go with an iframe-"workaround" described [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/11/ajax-style-file-uploading-using-hidden-iframe.html), e.g.

For your problem, why serialize is always empty have a look at the source of [jquery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js). The type of an input field is tested against this  regex

```
 /^(?:color|date|datetime|datetime-local|email|hidden|month|number|password|range|search|tel|text|time|url|week)$/i
```

As you can see the type "file" isn't part of that and so jquery won't serialize this sort of input field.

Answer (score 1):

checkout this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6dtN/2/). it sets up the basic html and JS via jQuery to use upload via iframe. a nice way to upload files "asynchronously" ;)